# looking for java library to work with PSD format

Tags: java, photoshop, psd

I'm looking for a java library to work with PSD format(Photoshop). Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try a Google query before posting here? I get lots of hits.

Comment: Thank you man, google is a very good website, never know about it

Answer (score 12):

Probably very late, but as this page is pretty high ranked on google when searching "java psd library" I'll share my experience.

-As Boris said the java-psd-library is read only.
It has trouble reading recent CS4 format. If you ever find yourself with an error opening a psd file, opening it in Gimp 2.8 and saving it again will probably fix the issue.

-As I needed to work on layered graphic files, I took time to search for an alternative. The PSD format is proprietary and access to specs seems restricted.
I found that the OpenRaster format is a pretty good alternative : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenRaster
It has open specs and it's really simple. It's a zipped file containing layers as png and a descriptor file. Gimp handles this format quite well and it's easy to export a psd file to an ora file.
You can find some Java tools to manipulate them. It's a part of a more vast project which is still in Alpha : https://code.google.com/p/mediaz/

Hope it'll help people.

Answer (score 7):

I'm late to the party, just want to mention that I've written an [ImageIO plugin for the PSD format](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#adobe-photoshop-document-psd) available at GitHub.

As the other libraries mentioned, it is read-only and does not support text or effect layers, but does read rasterized layers and composite image through the standard `javax.imageio` API, which may be of use for many.

The plugin will read any known versions of the PSD format, including the "Large file format" (aka PSB).

Answer (score 3):

there is a project called java-psd-libraray for parsing PSD files in Java.

URL: http://code.google.com/p/java-psd-library/

This library is not familiar with creating PSD files it is reader only. There is not possible read effect from PSD with this, but there is extension on [github](https://github.com/inevo/java-psd-library/tree/layer_effects). I don't know how good it is beacuse effects are changed with every version of PSD file.

Anyway this is the best libraray for reading PSD files written in Java.

Comment: Great library! Is there also a support for smart objects?