# How to extract preview image from a psd file; using Java

Tags: java, graphicsmagick, psd

As of version 1.3.24 graphicsmagick doesn't support the PSD format anymore. What alternatives are there to convert a psd file into a tiff or jpg or at least extract the contained preview image? I need to do this with Java, I could call an external process via CLI, of course (that's what I do with gm all the time).

Comment: [At this point, I'd like to take a moment to speak to you about the Adobe PSD format.](https://github.com/gco/xee/blob/master/XeePhotoshopLoader.m#L108)

Comment: LOL. Not a second do I doubt that comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834306/looking-for-java-library-to-work-with-psd-format

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Okay, the format *is* pretty bad, as it has survived a series of evolutions, rather than a major rewrite. But it all fairness, Adobe *has* made a decent attempt at [documenting the PSD format](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/). I have made a Java ImageIO plugin based on the information in there. :-)