# How to read PSD format image by Java?

Tags: java, image, swing, psd

I am developing a java swing based application which show thumbnail of any format(jpg,png) images. For that, at first I read the image file by `ImageIO.read(file name)` and then create thumbnail of it. But it shows null pointer exception when read PSD format file.

I use ideli library for read PSD type file but it requires subcription/paid. So there have any free library to read PSD type file in Java?

```
image = ImageIO.read(new File(i));
thumb = Thumbnails.of(image).size(140,100).outputFormat("png").asBufferedImage();
ImageIO.write(thumb, "png", new File("thumb.png"));
```

By above code, I can read (without PSD) image file and create thumbnail  of image.

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html), PSD is not a supported format.

You might find some value from a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834306/looking-for-java-library-to-work-with-psd-format).

Comment: I already read this doc.I ask for any free library because I already use a paid library.